# How to make a Rails model read-only except for specified attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, methods

I have a rails active record model `Application` and need to make it read-only.

I know that having a before_validation method with:

```
if locked

  def readonly?
    true
  end

end
```

Will allow me to make it readonly.

The only issue is that, when I need to disable readonly mode, I can not change the `locked` value to false because the model is already read-only.

I know that `attr_readonly :name, :email, :price` etc. will allow me to make specific attributes readonly, I am looking for the inverse of this to only allow specific attributes.

Is there a way to make this read-only method except specific attributes?

Comment: You can store settings into a DB table as json string or use some gem like https://github.com/huacnlee/rails-settings-cached

Comment: @iGian - Is there any other way that doesn't require adding a gem? I was hoping there is a built in method. Otherwise, is there a way to set read only status on a model based on one value within the model?

Comment: You can define a model `Settings`, where each column stores a specific parameter. Or store the information in rows as a `json` string. Then, the validation of an action requires to access the `Settings` and check which operation is allowed. Also you could access `Settings` from the controller, to lock `edit` and `new` or whathever.

Comment: @iGian - The only issue I have with that is that: If my model is 'Applications', then I need to lock each of the applications within depending of if the read only attr is true. A setting model will work, if I wanted to make all applications read only, but not if I need to make individual records read only.

Comment: Add a flag to each record (new column), accessible only to users with privileges.

Comment: The attribute that I made is named locked. I am locking using a method in in model like this: `def lock()
    self.locked = true
    save(validate: false)
  end` But, how can I get the model to check locked each time a query to the model is made?

Comment: Don't hard code by `read_only`, but check the flag (see my previous comment) by callbacks: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html -- Side: I suggest to move some comments of yours in the original post, so it appear clearer what you are trying to accomplish.